This answer doesn't comply with HSE rules and/or best practices
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/53844/12489

श्रीरामचन्द्र चरणौ शरणं प्रपद्ये।

This line needs to be removed.  HSE is not a place to publicly display devotion.  It is a site about Hinduism.

In the eighteenth incarnation, the Lord appeared as King Rāma. In order to perform some pleasing work for the demigods, He exhibited superhuman powers by controlling the Indian Ocean and then killing the atheist King Rāvaṇa, who was on the other side of the sea. Therefore , it's supreme.

Ravana was a devotee of Brahma from whom he obtained enormous powers and conqured most of the world.  He composed the famous Siva Tandava Stotram and was rewarded with the Chandrahaasa sword by Siva.
the alleged quote from Mahabharata has no chapter/line numbers.
All other citations except those from Srimad Bhagavatam are from obscure/unknown texts.  these citations need to be backed up electronically and Acharyas' opinions about their authenticity need to be provided.
HSE is intended to be a store of authentic knowledge about ALL of Hinduism and not a vehicle to make selective citations and reinterpret everything with a sectarian axe to grind.

Meta post is not required always. You could flag the post.
